# Moto G call recording issue

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am having below snippet in call recording example.

```
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
//      recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
        recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        //recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        //recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recorder.start();
```

On Moto G 1st Gen Lollipop 5.0.2, I'm not able to hear the incoming voice.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Hey, did u find a solution to that issue?

Comment: no, I think it is still an open issue